# Length of a Shadow Cast on a Sphere

Tags: geometry, circles, classical-mechanics, spheres, arc-length

I'm doing a project for a classical mechanics class about shadows cast on a sphere. Though the topic is physics-ish, the derivation is entirely math and geometry. Below is my derivation, but I'd appreciate a second pair of eyes to check it over. I've yet to really define the constraints on $\theta$ or whether to take the + or - sign of the $\pm$.

---

Meta: This post proposes an answer to the same question posed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972783/length-of-a-shadow-cast-by-an-object-on-a-sphere) but my diagram is different so don't take my setup to be the same.[image]

> In the left diagram, a vertical object of height $H$ sits normal to the surface of the sphere (reduced to a circle for simplicity). Incoming light casts a shadow (beneath $\lambda$) at an angle $\vartheta$ from the surface of the object. This shadow is a distance $\mathcal S = R\alpha$ from the base of the object, where $R$ is the radius of the sphere, and $\alpha$ is the angle from the base to the tip of the shadow, as measured from the center of the sphere.
>
> The right diagram is a close-up of the triangle constructed in the left diagram.

From the two diagrams above it is evident that $R\cos\alpha+\varepsilon = R$.

$\implies \varepsilon = R - R\cos\alpha$

$\implies H + \varepsilon = H + R - R\cos\alpha$

Using Pythagoras on the rightmost figure we have,

$\begin{aligned}\lambda^2&=\left(H+R-R\cos\alpha\right)^2 + R^2\sin^2\alpha
\\&= \left(H + R(1-\cos\alpha)\right)^2 + R^2\sin^2\alpha\\&= H^2 + 2HR(1-\cos\alpha) + R^2(1-\cos\alpha)^2 + R^2\sin^2\alpha\\&= H^2 + 2HR - 2HR\cos\alpha + R^2(1 - 2\cos\alpha + \cos^2\alpha) + R^2\sin^2\alpha\\&= H^2 + 2HR +R^2 -2HR\cos\alpha-2R^2\cos\alpha + R^2\cos^2\alpha+ R^2\sin^2\alpha\\&= H^2 + 2HR +R^2 - (2HR + 2R^2)\cos{\alpha} + R^2\\&= (H^2 + 2HR +2R^2) - (2HR + 2R^2)\cos\alpha\end{aligned}$

The rightmost figure also tells us that $\lambda\sin\vartheta = R\sin\alpha$.

$\implies \lambda^2 = \cfrac{R^2\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\vartheta}$
$= \cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}(1 - \cos^2{\alpha})$
$= \cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta} - \cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}\cos^2\alpha$

Equating these two expressions for $\lambda^2$ gives,

$\cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta} - \cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}\cos^2{\alpha}= (H^2 + 2HR +2R^2) - (2HR + 2R^2)\cos\alpha$

$\implies \cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}\cos^2\alpha- (2HR + 2R^2)\cos{\alpha} + \left(H^2 + 2HR +2R^2 - \cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}\right) = 0$

Noting that this result is a quadratic equation in terms of $\cos^2\alpha$, we can solve for $\cos\alpha$ using the quadratic formula:

$\cos\alpha = \cfrac{(2HR + 2R^2) \pm \sqrt{(2HR + 2R^2)^2 -4\cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}\left(H^2 + 2HR +2R^2 - \cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}\right)}}{2\cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}}$

Finally, using the arc-length identity $\mathcal S = R\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is measured in radians, we obtain the distance a shadow is cast as measured on a sphere (given the setup described in the figure above):

$\begin{aligned}\mathcal S&= R\arccos\left(\cfrac{(2HR + 2R^2) \pm \sqrt{(2HR + 2R^2)^2 -4\cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}\left(H^2 + 2HR +2R^2 - \cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}\right)}}{2\cfrac{R^2}{\sin^2\vartheta}}\right)
\end{aligned}$
**P.S.** In case my professor sees this and thinks I just copied it rather than posting it, I'll state the following: The content of this post is original to J. White who's taking PHYS 331 in the Winter 2020 semester at McGill.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be shorter, but, since you have extracted a _right-triangle_ with an _altitude_ $R\sin\alpha$, you could also use the _Euclid's theorem_.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

HINTS:

Your labels for $\alpha,\theta$

Solve for $x,$ by eliminating/ plugging in for $y$

$$ (x-(H+R))^2 +y^2= R^2,\; y = x \tan \theta \;;$$
Plug into
$$ \alpha= \tan^{-1}\frac{ x \tan \theta}{R}, s = R \alpha . $$